# Copy MIME parts from mail to another document - converting MIME <-> Richtext

Tags: java, email, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus

Hello Domino programmers!

I work on a lotus database + XPages and i ran into a following problematic situation:

I receive mails in form of "Memo" documents directly to my database. I would like to separate attachments and body of mail (with embedded images) into two richtext fields. To achieve this I made a java agent. Idea seems fine for my solution, but every time I try to copy a Richtextitem "Body" from mail to another document, a created item contains Richtext elements instead of MIME parts. It would be fine, but through this a whole message seems to lose the formatting.. I know there exists a "switch" that should prevent this from happening - session.setConvertMime(false). I used it before accessing a source document but without any effect - my Richtext fields are blank instead.

So I have a bunch of questions:

- Is there a way to copy body of a Memo document to store a content of email formatted? I'm interested in possibility to review email from XPages.
- When I use a FileDownload, FileUpload and RichTextControl - is it recommendable to keep content of a message and attachments in the same field on back-end document?

Any help will be appreciated.

//
I use 9.0 designer and 9.0 development server.

// Here is a code i currently use

```
          Session session = getSession();
          String TMPSAVE_PATH = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
          Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
          View v = db.getView("Inbox");
          ViewEntryCollection vec = v.getAllEntries(); 
          ViewEntry entry = vec.getFirstEntry();
          while(entry!=null)
          {
              Document mailDoc = entry.getDocument();
              Document newDoc = db.createDocument();
              newDoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Ticket");
              newDoc.replaceItemValue("Title","[MAIL] " + mailDoc.getItemValueString("Subject"));
              newDoc.replaceItemValue("Status", "0");
              newDoc.computeWithForm(true, true);
              newDoc.save(false,true);

              RichTextItem rtiOLD = (RichTextItem)mailDoc.getFirstItem("Body");
              newDoc.removeItem("Description");
              RichTextItem rtiDESC = newDoc.createRichTextItem("Description");
              rtiDESC.appendRTItem(rtiOLD);
              newDoc.removeItem("Attachment");
              RichTextItem rtiATT = newDoc.createRichTextItem("Attachment");
              newDoc.save(false,true);

              List attachmentList = new ArrayList();
              Vector vector = rtiDESC.getEmbeddedObjects();

              if(vector.size()>0)
              {                  
                  for (int i = 1; i <= vector.size(); i++)
                  {
                      String attachmentName = vector.get(i-1).toString();
                      EmbeddedObject obj = (EmbeddedObject)vector.get(i-1);                   
                      if(obj!=null)
                      {
                          attachmentList.add(attachmentName);
                          obj.extractFile(TMPSAVE_PATH + attachmentName);
                          obj.remove();
                      }
                  }
              }

              newDoc.save(false,true); 

              if(attachmentList.size()>0)
              { 
                  for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) 
                  {
                      rtiATT.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", TMPSAVE_PATH + attachmentList.get(i), (String)attachmentList.get(i));
                      File file = new File(TMPSAVE_PATH + attachmentList.get(i));
                      file.delete();
                  }
              }
              newDoc.save(false,true);
          }           
          entry = vec.getNextEntry(entry);
```

//Changed title to be suitable for the problem.

Comment: Show your code. That's the only way we'll be able to see see why your content is not being copied correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by multiple using methods NotesDocument.getFirstItem and then NotusDocument.AppendItemValue so I could just simply copy whole message body.

Comment: where u able to solve dis problem, i lost all inline image when ever i try to save mail mimeemtity to another document, can u pls update above script that i can see ur solotion to dis?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this IBM technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21200321) explains your problem. The call to AppendRTItem() does not copy the $File items that are associated with the attachments.

Comment: So, is there any workaround? I mean, in addition to attachments, all formatting is lost, so mail design is lost too..

Plus note refers to Lotusscript code, while agent is written in Java.

Comment: You need to reattach the attachments. Formatting should not be lost for MIME items if you use ConvertMIME=false, but now that I think about it more... you may have to use the NotesMIMEEntity class to selectively copy only the non-attachment child entities to your Description item. There are only minor differences in naming and syntax between the LotusScript classes and the Java classes.

Comment: I just got MIMEEntity of body using getMIMEEntity java method. How can I copy this entity to another document? I tried Document.copyItem method but it seem to copy just one MIME part.

For now it would be fine even without seperation of attachments, cause I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you create your new rich text item and then use: rtiDESC = newDoc.copyItem(rtiOLD,"Description");

Comment: Yes, but to keep orginal content I have to use ConvertMIME = false, and I call RichTextItem rtiOLD = (RichTextItem)mailDoc.getFirstItem("Body"), I get invalid RichTextItem error.